# Make Python string a raw string

Tags: python, python-2.7, rawstring

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
from sys import exit as EXIT


File = os.path.realpath(__file__)
dir = os.path.dirname(File)
os.chdir(dir)
path_file = os.path.join(dir,"path.txt")
filo = open(path_file)
lines = filo.readlines()

if len(lines) == 1:
    path = lines[0]
else:
    raw_input("Too many lines... ")
    EXIT()

FILE = open(path)
```

When I run it I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py/Zebra/zebra.py", line 20, in <module>
    FILE = open(path)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\file.txt'
```

If the path would be hard-coded then I could do something like
    path = r"C:\path\to\file"

But since the variable was defined by other methods, I am not sure now to fix this :(

Comment: I think your problem is not related to the raw string - the escape of backslashes looks correct.

Comment: Does the file definitely exist at that path?

Comment: From the first line I will assume you're running Linux. `'C:\\Users...'` should not exist on a Linux system and thus it is not able to find it. If it is so, can you try a valid path and see if the error continues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind `r' '` is to write [raw string literals](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), because it changes the way python escape characters. If it happens to be a value from a variable, as you stated above, you don't need to use `r' '` because you are not explicitly writing a string literal.

Either way, I think this will do:

```
path = r'%s' % pathToFile
```

**EDIT:**
Also, as commented to the question, you should really be **sure** the path exists.